# Accidentally deleted the only Azure subscription owner role

Tags: azure, cloud, subscription, rbac

I accidentally deleted the only azure owner role of my subscription. Any idea how can I get that restore? I can only login now at azure portal and when I click on subscriptions it is keep loading, nothing is coming.

Comment: open a support ticket. There's nothing we can do about it

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio thanks for the reply. I resolved this. As I am also a global administrator so I created an Azure AD User, assigned the global admin role to it. Login to azure portal with that new account, and re-assigned the Owner role to my original account which I accidentaly deleted. Now Its Working fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this myself. As I am also a global administrator so I created an Azure AD User, assigned the global admin role to it. Login to azure portal with that new account, and re-assigned the Owner role to my original account which I accidentally deleted. Now Its Working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened with me today and even after being "Global Admin" to Azure AD, I was unable to modify the permissions as the "Role Assignment" options were appearing disabled.

These are the steps that I followed:

1. I logged in to Azure Portal with the MS Live ID(@outlook.com) using which we got the MS Azure subscription registered(Root ID or Account Owner ID).
2. Then went to the Azure subscription --> IAM --> Add Role Assignment. This option was enabled this time!
3. To be on safer side now, created a Security Group in Azure AD with 3 Azure Administrators and then made this Group as "Owner" to the Azure Subscription.